# How To Edit Supported Cultures In a Silverlight Project

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

Is there any way to edit list of cultures supported by a SL project in Visual Studio 2008 using GUI?

Currently I'm doing this by changing content of `<SupportedCultures>` node in the .cproj file manually. For example:

```
<SupportedCultures>
en, de, es, fr, ja, zh-CN
</SupportedCultures>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No. I continue to do this in Visual Studio 2010, too. It isn't much of a bother, though.